# What are the odds (or how would I calculate the odds) of being dealt no ace in 10 hands, 20 hands and 30 hands?

Tags: odds

As it says in the title...I just had 30 hands with no aces. What are the odds?

(standard NLHE I should add, not 5 card stud etc)

Answer (score 1):

The odds of not being dealt an ace in a 2-card hand is the the odds of being dealt two non-aces.  There are 48 non-aces in the deck, so this is (48/52) * (47/51), or 85% for one hand.

The odds of it for any number of hands n is that product raised to the nth power.

P(n) = (2256/2652)^n

| number hands | probability no aces |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.851 |
| 10 | 0.198 |
| 20 | 0.039 |
| 30 | 0.008 |

Comment: Ah... Much simpler than I was making it in my head! Stats was never my strong suit. Thanks a lot.